# shutil copyfile() throws Errno2: No such file or directory, by the destination file

Tags: python, shutil, file-copying

So,I thought at first I had made a mistake in the Path Name for the file's destination, but I went to the folder through the terminal, copied the path to my code, permissions are set to 777, I just donc get what's going on. Worth noting also, that at some point it did work.

heres my terminal's output:

**My lists:**

```
FileNameList: ['A-1-[1/2]-TxsMncpls2023.pdf', 'A-1-[2/2]-TxsMncpls2023.pdf']
PathFile: ['/Users/fredericpepin/TwoWaysSyncNAS/Bloc/Malouin/ComptesTaxes/taxation-révisée-2023.pdf', '/Users/fredericpepin/TwoWaysSyncNAS/Bloc/Malouin/ComptesTaxes/taxes-minicipales-2023.pdf']
```

**Traceback:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/fredericpepin/TwoWaysSyncNAS/Bloc/#GUI_Input for Bill managing.py", line 275, in <module>
    sh.copyfile(src,dst)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/shutil.py", line 258, in copyfile
    with open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/fredericpepin/TwoWaysSyncNAS/Bloc/Malouin/Factures/2023/A-1-[1/2]-TxsMncpls2023.pdf'
```

and here is the code for this section:

```
year = 2023 ##int
FileNameList = ['A-1-[1/2]-TxsMncpls2023.pdf', 'A-1-[2/2]-TxsMncpls2023.pdf']
i=0
for e in PathFile:
    src = e
    dst = f'/Users/fredericpepin/TwoWaysSyncNAS/Bloc/Malouin/Factures/{str(year)}/{FileNameList[i]}'
    i+=1
    sh.copyfile(src,dst)
```

I don't know wheter the list is the problem?

I'm using macOs

Comment: I think in windows filenames should not contain **/**. are you on windows?

Comment: @Nesi Do you mean Unix-like? There it's definitely a problem.

Comment: I'm on macOs (UNIX like os), so the slashes are normally that way. Plus I simply copy pasted the path from the terminal

Comment: @frédéric-pepin we are talking about the / inside this 'A-1-[1/2]-TxsMncpls2023.pdf'

Comment: It doesn't look like it should be possible to have a filename with a `/` in Unix. It would be useful to see the output of: `ls /Users/fredericpepin/TwoWaysSyncNAS/Bloc/Malouin/Factures/2023/`

Comment: `A-1-[1/2]-TxsMncpls2023.pdf` is definitely an invalid filename.  It would interpret `A-1-[1` as a subdirectory, and `2]-TxsMncpls2023.pdf` as the actual filename.

Comment: You certainly cannot have / as part of a filename on any Unix-style system. I doubt if you can on Windows either. [ Do people still use Windows? ]

Comment: if you are using the **full** pathname in windows, you need the drive letter like this: `C:/Users/admin/Downloads/some_file.py`.  So it appears as though you have used an attempt at a relative path name.